# SwiftUI Animate Bar Between Custom Segment Control

Tags: swiftui

I have designs for a custom Tab component (Segmented Control). The implementation is pretty basic, but one of the design requirements is for the bar at the bottom to animate between the different options (move on x axis + grow to new text size).

I have the below (WIP) implementation that statically swaps the items, but I am not sure how to get the animation between the items.

Using overlay allows for the bar to dynamically take up the full width of the parent, but I wonder if there needs to be a seperate bar that animates between the items.

Here is the WIP code:

```
struct Tabs: View {

    @Binding var selectedTab: Int
    var tabs: [Tab]

    init(_ selectedTab: Binding<Int>, tabs: [Tab]) {
        self._selectedTab = selectedTab
        self.tabs = tabs
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 12) {
                ForEach(self.tabs.indices) { tabIndex in
                    let tab = self.tabs[tabIndex]
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.selectedTab = tabIndex
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text(tab.title)
                            .font(.body.weight(.medium))
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .padding(.bottom, 8)
                            .padding(.top, 2)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 4)
                            .if(tabIndex == self.selectedTab) {
                                $0.overlay(
                                    Rectangle()
                                        .fill(Color.blue)
                                        .frame(width: .infinity, height: 3),
                                    alignment: .bottom
                                )
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the expected design (note the underline bar, that is what I need to animate).

[image]

Comment: A similar question but uses `matchedGeometryEffect`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69473269

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new view under each tab during selection, this will not work. For SwiftUI, these will be different views, so they won't animate the position change.

Instead, I suggest you read this great [article](https://www.answertopia.com/swiftui/swiftui-stack-alignment-and-alignment-guides/) about alignment guides, especially the *Cross Stack Alignment* part.

So, using alignment guides, we can bind one of the view guides, such as center, to the selected center of the tab.

But we also need to get the width somehow. I do this with `GeometryReader`.

[image]

```
struct Tabs: View {

    @State var selectedTab = 0
    var tabs: [Tab]

    @State private var tabWidths = [Int: CGFloat]()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(alignment: .crossAlignment, spacing: 0) {
                HStack(spacing: 12) {
                    ForEach(self.tabs.indices) { tabIndex in
                        let tab = self.tabs[tabIndex]
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.selectedTab = tabIndex
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text(tab.title)
                                .font(.body.weight(.medium))
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .padding(.bottom, 8)
                                .padding(.top, 2)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 4)
                                .if(tabIndex == self.selectedTab) {
                                    $0.alignmentGuide(.crossAlignment) { d in
                                        d[HorizontalAlignment.center]
                                    }
                                }
                        }.sizeReader { size in
                            tabWidths[tabIndex] = size.width
                        }
                    }
                }
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(width: tabWidths[selectedTab], height: 3)
                    .alignmentGuide(.crossAlignment) { d in
                        d[HorizontalAlignment.center]
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func sizeReader(_ block: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
        background(
            GeometryReader { geometry -> Color in
                DispatchQueue.main.async { // to avoid warning
                    block(geometry.size)
                }
                return Color.clear
            }
        )
    }
}

extension HorizontalAlignment {
    private enum CrossAlignment: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            d[HorizontalAlignment.center]
        }
    }

    static let crossAlignment = HorizontalAlignment(CrossAlignment.self)
}
```

p.s. Don't use `.frame(width: .infinity)` to extend the view, use `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` instead.  Yes, you must split it into two modifiers if you want to provide a static `height`.

p.s.s. You should use `if` modifier very carefully. It's fine in this case, but in most cases it will break your animation, see [this article](https://www.objc.io/blog/2021/08/24/conditional-view-modifiers/) to understand why.

Comment: Awesome! Just what I needed. Thanks for the detailed explanation, makes sense why mine wasn't working.

I will have a read through those articles too

Answer (score 0):

Hope, This will help, you can try once.

Step 1: Created a Animate segment Controller view

```
struct AnimatedSegmentedControl: View {
let items: [String]
@Binding var selectedItemIndex: Int
 var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(items.indices) { index in
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.selectedItemIndex = index
                    }
                }) {
                    VStack{
                        Text(items[index])
                            .font(.headline)
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(index == selectedItemIndex ? Color(hex: "0F4D80", alpha: 1.0) : Color(hex: "35353A", alpha: 1.0))
                        ZStack {
                            Capsule()
                                .fill(Color.clear)
                                .frame(height: 2)
                            if index == selectedItemIndex {
                                Capsule()
                                    .fill(Color(hex: "0F4D80", alpha: 1.0))
                                    .frame(height: 2)
                               
                            }
else {
                                    Capsule()
                                        .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.4))
                                        .frame(height: 2)
                                }
                        }
                    }
                        
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / CGFloat(items.count))
                .background(Color.clear)
            }

            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / CGFloat(items.count), height: 2)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .offset(x: CGFloat(selectedItemIndex) * (geometry.size.width / CGFloat(items.count)))
                
        }
       // .animation(.easeInOut)
    }
    .frame(height: 50)
}}
```

Step 2: call from main view to segment view

```
struct TestView: View {
@State private var selectedItemIndex = 0
let items = ["History", "Favorites"]

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        AnimatedSegmentedControl(items: items, selectedItemIndex: $selectedItemIndex)
        Spacer()
        if selectedItemIndex == 1 {
            Text("History items containt details display here..")
        }
        else {
            Text("Favorite items containt Details display here..")
        }
        
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

}

```
struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    TestView()
}}
```

Below code will change from hexa to color.

```
extension Color {
init(hex: String, alpha: Double = 1.0) {
    var formattedHex = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)
    if formattedHex.hasPrefix("#") {
        formattedHex.remove(at: formattedHex.startIndex)
    }

    let scanner = Scanner(string: formattedHex)
    var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0

    if scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber) {
        self.init(
            .sRGB,
            red: Double((hexNumber & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: Double((hexNumber & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: Double(hexNumber & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            opacity: alpha
        )
        return
    }

    // Fallback color (black) if invalid hex string
    self.init(.sRGB, red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 1.0)
}}
```

**You can see the screenshot below**

[image]